# Is it possible to install vstest.console.exe 2013 with vstudio 2019?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to run build agents in my azure pipeline, but the code is written in VS 2013, so my tests are failing when I'm using VS 2019 installed on the server.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to just install the testing suite for VS 2013 without installing the whole IDE on the server.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why are the tests failing? What specific error are you encountering?

Comment: @DanWilson the failures are pretty standard related to the code itself. For example `Test method MSInvoiceXUnitTests.XMLValidatorTest.EDI_PreDataValidation_Fail threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null` There are a lot of tests failing, so fixing the tests will take a lot of effort. The tests run fine in VS2013, hence my question.

Comment: Build your own build agent machine, where you install VS2013. Then you can run the pipeline on that custom agent.

Answer (score 2):

*The Microsoft-hosted agent pool provides 7 virtual machine images to choose from:*

- *Visual Studio 2019 Preview on Windows Server 2019 (windows-2019)*
- *Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2016 (vs2017-win2016)*
- *Visual Studio 2015 on Windows Server 2012R2 (vs2015-win2012r2)*
- *Windows Server 1803 (win1803) - for running Windows containers*
- *macOS X Mojave 10.14 (macOS-10.14)*
- *macOS X High Sierra 10.13 (macOS-10.13)*
- *Ubuntu 16.04 (ubuntu-16.04)*

*You can try it first and see if it works for your build or deployment. If not, you can use a self-hosted agent.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent

Follow the below document to create a self-hosted agent and install VS2013 on it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops